# How could Sri Rama communicate with the monkeys?

Tags: ramayana, rama, lakshmana, vanaras

How could Sri Rama and Lakshmana communicate with the monkeys? It seems just impossible to any sensible person.But as it is written in our scriptures, it must have some deep inner meaning.

Can anybody throw light on this?

Comment: These were no ordinary monkeys.  They were children that Devas had Vanara women in order to provide an army for Rama.  These Vanaras even received education in Hindu scripture.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan please write an answer if possible

Comment: they were Vanaras (van + nara) and not monkeys...van means forest so Vanara means Naras (with tail) living in forest...or u can say half human and half monkeys...

Comment: @Lakhi So why are they including Hanumanji depicted with tails in all images and idols?

Comment: @Partha thats why half human and half monkey...have u seen hanumanji walking on four legs...? other than face and tail they were similar to humans...

Comment: Question seems to be,.. What was the language or gesture code adopted between humans and between humans & vanaras?

Comment: There are 4 ways of communication as in rig veda